# X-Forwarded-For field in lighttpd using ::ffff:192.168.1.45 IP Format

Tags: lighttpd

With lighttpd version 1.4.40, I can see that the X-Forwarded-For field is being set to ::ffff:192.168.1.45

With older lighttpd version 1.4.35, It used to be just 192.168.1.45

Is there a way to get lighttpd 1.4.40 to use X-Forwarded-For as 192.168.1.45 instead of ::ffff:192.168.1.45 ?

I understand the reasons why the ::ffff is present, but I want to see if my application is misbehaving because of this extra ::ffff. So it would be useful to remove this and test.

Comment: I tried removing it but application didn't show any difference. So its not a problem. But what i did was a hardcode. It will be useful to know if there is a lighttpd config that can remove the ffff

Comment: Yes, lighttpd can be configured.  Have you made any attempt to find your answer in the lighttpd documentation?  (clearly not)  https://wiki.lighttpd.net/